# Idiomatic way to use a computed value as a pattern in match

Tags: rust

What is the best way to use a value computed at runtime as one of the patterns in a match?

I have a value (`byte`) that I need to match against other values. Some of the values are fixed (b'0'..b'9'). Others are computed at runtime (`c = some_function()`).

My current solution is to use a fake variable and a if guard (i.e. `k if (k == c)`), but it does not look very nice to me. I tried using just `c` but that gets interpreted as a catch-all variable, rather than substituted for the value of `c` in that context.

The following code snippet shows the problem: ([also on playpen](http://is.gd/NJ1J8q))

```
fn main() {
    fun(b'5', 0);
    fun(b'C', 0);
    fun(b'C', 2);
}

fn fun(byte: u8, i: uint) {
    let CHARS = b"ABCDEFGH";
    let c = CHARS[i];

    let msg = match byte {
        b'0'..b'9' => "numeric",
        // c => "same char", // <-- I would had preferred this
        k if (k == c) => "same char",
        _ => "different char",
    };

    println!("fun({}, {} [{}]) = {}", byte, i, c, msg);
}
```

Is this the most idiomatic construct that Rust can offer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, yes, you should use pattern guards for this.

To make it possible there should be a way to differentiate plain bindings and equality checks. Scala, for example, does this based on variable case: if it starts with capital letter, it is an equality check; otherwise it is a pattern binding. There is no such mechanism in Rust, so no, it is impossible now.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I started a discussion about equality checks at http://discuss.rust-lang.org/t/matching-variable-values/405.